# How to Consume JSON as input in PUT and POST method of REST webservice in android?

Tags: java, android, json, rest, android-webservice

I want to consume rest webservice get and post method json format in android application. But I dont know how to consume and get the data from server can u please guide me to get and post the json data to server in android platform.

Comment: The best solution is usin Retrofit you can see tihs toturial [Retrofit — Getting Started and Create an Android Client]https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to use on Android for this is the [Retrofit library](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). See their how to to accomplish this pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

Google states on their Android Developers page to use Volley for HTTP Requests.
About Volley: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html
Request: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

You can use this Tutorial to implement your stuff (it provides more information):
http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/